# How to describe something callable with properties in TypeScript? And how to call the below function?

Tags: typescript

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
console.log(doSomething({description="how are you", (9)=>return true;})) //error
```

I'm trying to call the above function with some arguments but I'm getting error as below

"This expression is not callable.
Type '{ description: string; }' has no call signatures.(2349)
(property) description: any"

How do I call this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your function field a name so you can refer to it later. Also you have some syntax error while passing the object as parameter:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  call: (someArg: number) => boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn.call(6));
}
console.log(doSomething({description: "how are you", call: (x: number) => true }))
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSwEYEN0BsIDEBXAO0WFQHtioBeKAbwCgooATBFVMcqgLinjA0xAOYBuZlESYcOfgAp4FALYQAgshH9ihZegjIAlLQB8UdBQp5MxCQF8JAMxJlK1VhQDKKiMAAWqKLyjsT8cEhoWLgELjzExkwsiFRKeAB0OBQiwcRp7BFccVAA1FAARFDIvoTIxBCs5SVQIWnSsvIAbIaG9ozJxKkQGVnyHt6q-oHZ9Pmc3G78ZX4UAO5QmFVQIBSEZQA0UjJyUPIAHtq6+kamUEKE0HbdQA)

Answer (score 0):

No problem! You can attach properties to any object, including functions, with `Object.assign`.

The beginning of your code is already valid, and the end will work if you write it like this:

```
let described = Object.assign((x: number) => true, { description: "how are you" });
console.log(doSomething(described));
```

In case you're interested, here how you can write a helper function that attaches just one property:

```
/** Adds a property to any object, and returns the same object with a type that includes 
    the new property. */
export function attachProp<T extends {}, PName extends string, PType>(
    obj: T, prop: PName, value: PType
) {
    (obj as any)[prop] = value;
    return obj as T & { [p in PName]: PType };
}
```

Usage:

```
let described = attachProp((x: number) => true, 'description', "how are you");
console.log(doSomething(described));
```